# unable to uninstall and install IIS and windows process activation roles on server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5

I am writing this question in superuser after the lots of search on internet, problem is that,I have install windows server 2008 r2 and successfully install AD and IIS. due to some of issue,I have try to remove iis but getting fatal error during the uninstall process.

So that try to remove manually but after *windows process activation service* process getting crash. If I try to remote this feature getting too many error as below:

**try to remove *windows process activation service***

```
Windows Process Activation Service: Removal failed
Error: a.  Fatal error during installation
Error: Attempt to un-install .NET Environment failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
Error: Attempt to un-install Process Model failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
The following features were not removed:
Process Model
.NET Environment
Configuration APIs
```

**IIS 7.5 installation failed**

```
Web Server (IIS): Installation failed
Error: Attempt to install IIS Management Console failed with error code  0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
Error: Attempt to install Request Monitor failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
Error: Attempt to install Static Content Compression failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
Error: Attempt to install Request Filtering failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
Error: Attempt to install HTTP Logging failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
Error: Attempt to install HTTP Errors failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
Error: Attempt to install Static Content failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
Error: Attempt to install Default Document failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
Error: Attempt to install Directory Browsing failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
The following role services were not installed:
Web Server
  Common HTTP Features
     Static Content
     Default Document
     Directory Browsing
     HTTP Errors
  Health and Diagnostics
     HTTP Logging
     Request Monitor
  Security
     Request Filtering
  Performance
     Static Content Compression
  IIS Management Console
```

Also not able to install IIS roles on server, Is that any way for remote Roles/Feature forcefully ?

Comment: share (onedrive, dropbox) the log files from C:\Windows\logs\CBS

Comment: Plz find logs on https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9lYnZFbr6mbYWJDc2lFbEs1bmM&usp=sharing and I think, problem in .net 3.5 but I can not remove it because dependency with AD.:-

Answer (score 0):

there seams to be an issue when SMConfigInstaller is trying to update the config files in `%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\schema`, because something is not found `0x80070002`

```
Process output: [l:323 [323]"SMConfigInstaller[Error]: CApplicationHostConfigInstaller::GetParentElement m_spAppHostAdminManager->GetAdminSection failed. cbstrSectionName=system.applicationHost/listenerAdapters m_cbstrConfigCommitPath=MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST Error code: 0x80070002SMConfigInstaller[Error]: Installation failed with error: 0x80070002
```

But I don't use IIS, so I have no idea which config files are used here. Try to compare it with a clean system where it works.

Comment: thing is that, Previously I was deleted _inetsrv_ folder and _windows process activation_ service too. Current situation is that IIS not able to install and _windows process activation_ feature can't remove! I need to fresh install of IIS roles without remove AD.

Comment: ok, this explains the NOT FOUND error. Install a VM of Server 2008R2, activate IIS + Windows Process Activation and now copy the folder from the VM to your host and now try to uninstall both features on the host

Comment: I created new server and install iis; after copy inetsrv folder to old and was and iis successfully uninstall but after the install again, there is no iis,www,was services found in service.msc and I can't uninstall it, every time after the restart getting revert changes and getting same state.

Comment: share the new logs

Comment: Pls find new log;https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9lYnZFbr6mbdTkwX0xfcjNXNW8

Comment: this time I see a lot of 0x80073afc errors which means MUI files not found: ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_FOUND. So you also have MUI issues. The best is to try to repair Windows via inplace upgrade: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: Bad news; Unable to Upgrade Windows server 2008 r2 standard to standard and standard to Enterprise and etc...I think, Windows XP have good option for repair,,,

Comment: do you also get an error or what happens?